# Running a for loop until a condition is met but no iterator needed

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm still new to this so excuse the lack of knowledge and possibly poor syntax. I did search for an answer but I lack the vocab to find it.

Here's my code:

```
const pAequorFactory = (uniqueNumber, dnaArray) => {
    return {
        specieNum: uniqueNumber,
        _dna: dnaArray,
        mutate () {
            const randBaseNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this._dna.length);
            for (let i = 0; this._dna[randBaseNum] !== returnRandBase(); i++) {
                this._dna[randBaseNum] = returnRandBase();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a factory function that takes a unique number and an array of 15 strings (DNA bases) and creates an object. To remind you, there are 4 DNA bases - A, T, C, and G. The `mutate()` method is supposed to select a random base (item) in the array, and **change it to a different base** (it cannot remain the same).

**My problem:** I'm unsure how to run the comparison between current base and a random base until they don't match and then set the current base to that non-matching random one. The code as it is will just keep resetting the base whether or not it was different.

I looked at `while` statements and was considering something like this:

```
mutate () {
    const randBaseNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this._dna.length);
    let baseToMutate = this._dna[randBaseNum];
    while (baseToMutate === this._dna[randBaseNum]) {
        baseToMutate = returnRandBase();
    }
    this._dna[randBaseNum] = baseToMutate;
}
```

This seems to work after 100 iterations and reviewing each one manually.

Is there a better way? I get the sense I'm missing something.

Also, any syntax corrections or identifications of code smells greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `returnRandBase()` function so it takes `baseToMutate` as an argument. The function should return a random base other than that. This can be done easily by removing the argument from the array of bases to select from.

```js
function returnRandBase(base) {
  const bases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G'];
  const index = bases.indexOf(base);
  bases.splice(index, 1);
  return bases[floor(Math.random() * bases.length)];
}

mutate() {
  const randBaseNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this._dna.length);
  let baseToMutate = this._dna[randBaseNum];
  this._dna[randBaseNum] = returnRandBase(baseToMutate);
}
```